# Sqlite error and Precompiling assets failed when I push heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I have set in the application.rb according with heroku docs about "Precompiling assets failed".

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Assets were precompiled successfully locally by run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I work with Rails 3.2.13. I have squlite3 in the gemfile.
When I try to push app on heroku I have such problem:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins...
...
rake aborted!
       Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:240:in `block in replace_gem'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_256ed4cc-34a4-4fed-8fdb-d5d5c459a1df/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: Docs states clearly to use postgresql, not sqlite. Also, have you add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to your gemfile? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set sqlite3 from your `gemfile`.

```
 Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

However, it will still not work because `sqlite3` isn't supported by heroku.

You can set `postgresql` which is supported by Heroku (gem 'pg' in your gemfile) instead.

You can follow [this official guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) to see how you can procede.

Answer (score 1):

add sqlite3 in your `Gemfile`

```
 gem 'sqlite3'
```